Open Warp (terminal) in Jetbrains software in Kubuntu
Warp is an intelligent terminal with built-in AI. I am using Warp terminal emulator in Kubuntu, and wish to use Warp as my terminal on PyCharm. I want to integrate this external tool in Jetbrains software including PyCharm.

This is a Question and Answer site; where the Question should outline the problem, and Answer provide a solution.  In this case, as asked/answered; the problem & solution are identical!  ??

Thank you for taking the time to post and share knowledge here but: i) please remove the CAPS as that is considered shouting and rude; ii) post a clear, specific question, about an Ubuntu tool and iii) post an answer that provides a solution to the problem in the question. As it stands, I have no idea what the issue here is or what the solution is solving.

@terdon I want to share the knowledge before someone comes across the issue Shortly. Please let me know if there is a better way to share solution knowledge without question. I will adjust the post to remove the SHOUTING.

@jsotola I removed the SHOUTING and updated the post.

@guiverc I want to share the knowledge before someone comes across the issue Shortly. Please let me know if there is a better way to share solution knowledge without question. I will adjust the post to remove the SHOUTING

what is the issue that you solved?

@jsotola if anyone wants to use an external tool (command prompt) on Jetbrains products on the Linux system. I am using Warp terminal and wish to use Warp as my terminal on Pycharm. The developers for warp do not have a solution on their website (docs.warp.dev/features/integrations-and-plugins). I was able to come up with a solution, and I want to share it with the community. That all

Currently Warp primarily uses OpenAI's GPT-3 model for its back-end AI capabilities. GPT-3 is weak compared to later versions of ChatGPT. On the other hand Warp offers some useful productivity features such as reusable workflows, IDE-like editing and command corrections.
This shows how to integrate Warp terminal with PyCharm.
File -> Settings -> External Tools > Click on +
Name: Open Warp
Description: Warp Terminal
Tool Settings
   Program: /usr/bin/warp-terminal (you may have a different path)
   Arguments: $ProjectFileDir$
   Working Directory: $ProjectFileDir$
Advanced Options
   unchecked Open console for tool output

